# How to page break output in powershell

Tags: powershell

For example, the command

```
get-help about_commonparameters
```

the output will scroll direct to the bottom, every time I have to scroll back to top to read. Is there any cmdlet to view powershell output page by page when the output is too long?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can pipe your command to `More`

```
get-help about_commonparameters | More
```

or use `Out-Host -Paging`

```
get-help about_commonparameters | Out-Host -Paging
```

Comment: but the one with "more" doesn't work in a remote PSSession. Is it because of the version?

Comment: `Out-Host` is native PS, whilst [more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/More_(command)) is actually a command that is native to multiple operating systems.

Comment: Also if you use `help` instead of `get-help` it will page by default (because it's a special built-in function, not a straight up alias). Beware also that paging doesn't work at all in the ISE console (it's not supported either via `help` or via `| more`).

Comment: Is it possible to scroll up? Or only downards?